# Почему PHPUnit не видит Laravel Фасады?

Tags: laravel, phpunit

**TestCase:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**CreatesApplication:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Сам тест:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Метод который тестируется:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Команда:**
`php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml tests/Unit`

**Версии:**
laravel 7
PHP 7.4
PHPUnit 9

Comment: Class 'DB' not found
Также не находить класс Config

Comment: Вне теста все работает!

Answer (score 0):

класс `TestCase` наследуется от `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`, а не от `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase`